# Twilio: missing recent calls logs for sub-accounts

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Folks, I've noticed that I'm missing Call logs for my sub-account in Twilio. The logs don't show in the main account either.

Is there any place that I should enable these logs?
As you can tell, I've received a bunch of calls, as shown in the graph, but no log is available.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing?
Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You should be able to see your call logs there. I would also check [the call logs section under Monitor in the console](https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/calls?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fvoice%2Fcalls%2Flogs%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1) to make sure they are there too.

If you can't find the call logs, then I would recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).